# Does Cosmos DB support Gremlin.net c# GLV?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin

I cannot find this information, and also I cannot find examples on how to use Gremlin.net c# GLV with a remote Cosmos DB graph. Someone knows anything about this? Thanks!

Comment: just out of curiosity whats "GLV " ?

Comment: It stands for "Gremlin Language Variants".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently CosmosDB does not support GLV's as they do not yet have Bytecode support.  They have told me that they are working on it and expect it to be available soon.